# Force redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, ssl

I am using Node Express as a server. I have configured my SSL certificate in NGINX PM2 server. When I hit `https://api.test.com`. I could get the response but when I do `http://api.test.com`, I couldn't get anything (i.e) it recognize it as a unknown URL.

How do I handle this? Should I do something in my code or in NGINX PM2?

**Code**

```
var express = require('express');
import application from './route';
const port = normalizePort(3000);
const server = http.createServer(application);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: You'll want to handle that in Nginx, not your node app.

Comment: Can you post me the condition for that or send any reference link

Answer (score 1):

Better to handle that in your nginx config. Here is a minimal example:

```
server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    server_name www.example.net;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443;
    server_name www.example.net;

    root   /vhosts/www.example.net;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/nginx/www.example.net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/nginx/www.example.net.key;



    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any configuration for your API URL so try this:

```
const application=require ('./route');
const express = require('express');
const app = express ();
app.use(application);
app.listen(4000,()=>console.log('connected'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration to your NGINX:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   location / {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
}
```

This will redirect any request from `http://{your_domain}` (supposing you are not using a port other than 80) to the `https://{your_domain}`.